# converting a JsonNode to a form?

Tags: java, json, jsf, primefaces, jackson

I have  a somewhat complex JsonNode as the root.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can traverse through the node and print its values but now I need to build a form file, or somehow send it to the jsf page as a form where it would look like this:

```
Glossary 
  title: ________
GlossDiv
  title: _________

//...rest...
```

is there a way to accomplish this with Jackson?

Comment: This question as it stands is in no way related to a problem with any of the tags. It is a question to have us suggest either a complete framework that already exists or how to implement such a solution. The answers can also be very opinionated. All three reasons it is not a 'good' question for StackOverflow, so I doubt you'll get answers or it survives the 'vote to close'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of discussing wether this question is valid or not. I wanted to provide feedback for anyone that faced the same problem I had.

My solutions was to traverse the JsonNode recursively and find the fields that I needed to build the form. 
I built the form using Dynaform
more info here:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/dynaform/basicUsage.jsf;jsessionid=9cke02lhk2h1oamfvrs6ehii